# Migrate .net project to .net Core with third party not migrated

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I have a C# .net project consisting on a dll on .net framework 4.6.2, running on windows, which is currently using some third parties. Our goal is to be able to use these dll API on Linux. I am able to migrate my dll to .net Core, but not this vendor third party. Obviously the system does not work and I guess that is due to this library which can not be migrated.

Is there any possibility to make all run on Linux?

Comment: You could try and use `mono` which should work (https://www.mono-project.com/)

Comment: If you have the source to the dependency change the build target to Mono or .Net Core and see if it works. If you don't ask the vendor nicely to do it for you. Otherwise you're out of luck and your best bet is a translation layer like WINE.

Comment: You do need the vendors to support .NET Core, or switch to other vendors, or replace such code with your own.

Comment: Even using Mono/WINE is no garuntee, as @LexLi says your best option is to contact the vendors and see what they offer.